# ExtJS 4.2 fieldcontainer vbox layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a form that has a fieldcontainer with `layout: {type:'vbox'}`.

I need to place two fields in the same line but the `radiogroup` is not aligned correctly. (I have attached the image for better understanding).

[image]

The form code is the following:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    fieldLabel: 'Date',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    allowBlank: false,
    disabled: true,
    value: new Date()
}, {
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    combineErrors: true,
    defaults: {
        hideLabel: true
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        width: 90,
        store: Ext.create('HolidayType', {
            autoLoad: true
        }),
        displayField: 'Description',
        valueField: 'HolidayTypeId',
        queryMode: 'local',
        allowBlank: false,

    }, {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        columns: 2,
        items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Official',
                name: 'RequestInAdvance',
                inputValue: 0,
                checked: true
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Personal',
                name: 'RequestInAdvance',
                inputValue: 1
            }

        ]
    }]

}, {
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Request',
    anchor: '70%',
    columns: 2,
    items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Payable',
            name: 'Request',
            inputValue: 0,
            checked: true
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Non Payable',
            name: 'Request',
            inputValue: 1
        }

    ]
},
```

Any clue on how can I get the desire behavior?

**UPDATE**

Here is the sencha fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a width for either your columns or the entire radio group:

```
xtype: 'radiogroup',
width: 200,
columns: 2,
items: [
    { boxLabel: 'Official', name: 'Request1', inputValue: 0, checked: true },
    { boxLabel: 'Personal', name: 'Request1', inputValue: 1 }
]
```

Check out the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8cj

Comment: It's not working... i just update my post with the Sencha Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The solution was to assign to each radio item a fixed width or flex:

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ci

```
items: [{
        boxLabel: 'Official',
        width: 80,
        padding: '0 0 0 22',
        name: 'Request1',
        inputValue: 0,
        checked: true
    }, {
        boxLabel: 'Personal',
        flex: 1,
        name: 'Request1',
        inputValue: 1
    }

]
```